# I am having trouble installing CakePHP on my Mac

Tags: php, macos, cakephp

I currently have XAMPP 5.6.8 and MAMP 3.2.1 installed on my computer. I also have Composer installed globally on my Mac. I tried all the suggestions in CakePHP but I am not able to install it. I looked all over this forum and none of the suggestions have worked for me. This is the error I get when I type in the commands into the terminal.

```
    Carloss-Mac-mini:~ Carlos_Zetroc$ composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app [CakePHP]
Installing cakephp/app (3.0.2)
  - Installing cakephp/app (3.0.2)
    Loading from cache

Created project in [CakePHP]
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.x-dev requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.1.x-dev requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.0-beta3 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.0-beta2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.0-beta1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.0-alpha2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.0-alpha1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.0-RC2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.0-RC1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.0 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for cakephp/cakephp ~3.0 -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.0.0, 3.0.0-RC1, 3.0.0-RC2, 3.0.0-alpha1, 3.0.0-alpha2, 3.0.0-beta1, 3.0.0-beta2, 3.0.0-beta3, 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.1.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev].
```

If anybody can help me out I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install and enable `ext-intl` on your system before installing `cakePhp`.

You will get the instruction [here](http://darraghenright.tumblr.com/post/22027208929/installing-intl-package-on-osx-lion)

Comment: I was able to get this far before it gave me an error:


`Carloss-Mac-mini:~ Carlos_Zetroc$ sudo pecl install intl
downloading intl-3.0.0.tgz ...
Starting to download intl-3.0.0.tgz (248,200 bytes)
....................................................done: 248,200 bytes
150 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20121113
Zend Module Api No:      20121212
Zend Extension Api No:   220121212
Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation and the
$PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable. Then, rerun this script.

ERROR: `phpize' failed`

Answer (score 0):

Check http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#requirements

`In XAMPP, intl extension is included but you have to uncomment extension=php_intl.dll in php.ini and restart the server through the XAMPP Control Panel.`

Comment: Sorry, I should've have mentioned that I tried this suggestion already and to no avail.

Comment: problem here seems like mac has inbuilt php installed and it uses that php version instead of the one XAMPP is running, i had used default configuration of PHP and installed MySQL seperately to install cakephp3.

Comment: could you check php -v in cli to confirm if that matches to XAMPP one

Comment: what about lamp ??

Answer (score 0):

The OSX answer to this is to go to "php-osx.liip.ch" and run this command for PHP 5.6 (Current stable) in your command line interface (CLI):
curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.6

After that is complete, establish the path to your PHP binary. You could use anything you want, but I used vim. Here is the command at the CLI:
"vim ~/.bash_profile"

This will lead you to a CLI text editor. I am told that some people may not have a "usr" directory, if not, feel free to make one. Please go elsewhere to see how to do this.

In the meanwhile, after you have executed "vim ~/.bash_profile", and inside the editor, feel free to press "i" for insert, and then type your path. The line is "export PATH="/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH". When you are done that, press escape and then ":wq" the ":" stand for "I wanna enter a command", and "wq" stands for "write and quit". When it is done, you will be returned to the command line.

You then enable you path by typing "source ~/.bash_profile". This will enable your new path. Close the CLI and restart it (if needed). Your new path will be "/usr/local/php5/bin/php". You can ascertain this if you type "which php" at the CLI.

This will now change the PHP universal from the default PHP that came with your Mac to the one you then specified. After which, feel free to bake with composer!